# get post data after submitting User Profile Form for success message

Tags: form, frontend, user-profile

After a logged-in user updates their profile on the front end, I'd like to redirect them to the same page but show a success message. I believe I can do this with `craft.request.getPost()` but it's not working for me.  Code below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="xyz">
```

and then

```
{% set success = craft.request.getPost('test') %}
{% if success %}
    Success message
{% endif %}
```

I can see "test" in my dev tools network tab but can't seem to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible – any input values added to your profile editing form (such as `test` in your case) will be included in the POST request to the [`users/saveUser`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionSaveUser-detail) controller action, but they won't actually be included in the redirect request back to the page (or to whatever URL is in your form's hidden `redirect` input).

As a workaround you can always check for the Flash notice that the UsersController sets after the user is successfully saved:

```
{% if craft.session.getFlash('notice') == 'User saved.'|t %}
    <p>Success message!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thank you so much! That worked and was really helpful!